# Is it safe to touch wire testing at low to medium voltage on a 14 or 12 gauge wire, 15 or 20 amp (current) circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, safety

Title is the question.

I'm using a Klein NCVT- 3 Voltage tester with a bar graph indicating voltage, and don't see anything in the [instructions](https://data.kleintools.com/sites/all/product_assets/documents/instructions/klein/NCVT-3_Instructions.pdf), and haven't ran across anything in a textbook or internet on this.

Voltage tester is testing at 2 out of 5 bars, still yellow, not red.

Voltage meter indicates <2 Volts.

Answer (score 3):

#### No!

A non-contact tester is used to double-check that a circuit is on/wired correctly (i.e., if it doesn't light up when expected, then there is a problem) or off (i.e., if it lights up when you **don't** not expected, then there is a problem). When used to check that a circuit is off, that is typically to make sure that it is safe to work on the wiring:

- Check circuit is on (using tester or by checking that light or appliance is on)
- Turn off breaker or remove fuse that you **think** controls the circuit
- Check circuit is off (using tester)

Remember, it takes a tiny fraction of an Ampere (GFCIs are rated in milliamps) at 120V to kill. **SAFETY FIRST**.

All that being said, there can be [phantom voltage from another circuit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136436/phantom-voltage-on-hot-wire-from-another-circuit) or there could be low voltage (telephone, network, doorbell, thermostat) - neither of which would be a problem.

The ground wire ("exposed copper wire") under **normal** circumstances will carry no current at all except when there is a fault in a circuit. There are limited circumstances (certain types of switches) where a very small amount of current is allowed on the ground wire. However, there are a number of other incorrectly wired situations that could cause dangerous current on the ground wire without any obvious fault, including:

- Ground used instead of neutral - e.g., need two hots + neutral + ground, only have hot + neutral + ground, improperly used neutral wire as a hot and ground wire as neutral
- Neutral and ground connected together where they shouldn't be, allowing all neutral current to flow on **both** neutral and ground
- Wires simply connected to the wrong places and "happen to work", but quite dangerous.

The only way to tell for sure is to check the voltage with a multimeter. The finger test is **NOT RECOMMENDED**.

Comment: Thank you. Voltage meter indicates >2 volts.

Comment: What do you mean by ">2 volts"? 3 > 2 and is no problem. 240 > 2 and is a big problem.

Comment: <2*... meant less than. how many volts would be harmful? likely it would be either fairly immaterial or 120?

Comment: To some degree, the current matters too. But as a *general* rule, voltage < 50V means network, telephone, doorbell, thermostat, etc. or is phantom voltage induced on a 120V or 240V wire. But a 12V car battery can give you quite a shock too...

Answer (score 1):

Safe to touch the insulation (that is undamaged)...

But **NOT** the conductor under any circumstances.

But for me, and this is IMHO, give me my favorite Fluke multimeter over that device as when I need to check for a loss of voltage ie 10% or 20% low etc it's the tool for the job.

Comment: thank you. for good measure, the conductor is the exposed copper wire.